# Does PDFQuery scraping library have its own "find_all()" method like BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, pdf

I'm trying to extract data from a PDF file. However, I have trouble finding a way to extract contents that contain the same characters.

For example,
`<LTTextLineHorizontal y0="632.076" y1="638.532" x0="142.518" x1="206.64" width="64.122" height="6.456" bbox="[142.518, 632.076, 206.64, 638.532]" word_margin="0.1"><LTTextBoxHorizontal y0="632.076" y1="638.532" x0="142.518" x1="206.64" width="64.122" height="6.456" bbox="[142.518, 632.076, 206.64, 638.532]" index="20">Date:20210326 </LTTextBoxHorizontal></LTTextLineHorizontal>`

`<LTTextLineHorizontal y0="554.604" y1="561.06" x0="142.518" x1="208.632" width="66.114" height="6.456" bbox="[142.518, 554.604, 208.632, 561.06]" word_margin="0.1"><LTTextBoxHorizontal y0="554.604" y1="561.06" x0="142.518" x1="208.632" width="66.114" height="6.456" bbox="[142.518, 554.604, 208.632, 561.06]" index="26">Date:20210410 </LTTextBoxHorizontal></LTTextLineHorizontal>\`.

I'm trying to extract both dates, but when I use
`pdf.pq('LTTextBoxHorizontal:contains("Date")').text()`, it only returns the first date `Date:20210326`. Is there a method that can return all the matched criteria in PDFQuery, like `find_all()` method in BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 0):

If you check type of `pdf.pq('LTTextBoxHorizontal:contains("Date")')` by
function `type()`, it will say `<class 'pyquery.pyquery.PyQuery'>`. Ok, since this object is PyQuery, you can go to https://pyquery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html
and read docs. You would like to read about method `.items()`. For short, lets assign `d = pdf.pq('LTTextBoxHorizontal:contains("Date")')`. Then you can iterate through all items `[i.text() for i in d.items('LTTextLineHorizontal')]`.

Comment: You can also use method `eq()` for  `d('LTTextLineHorizontal').eq(0).text()` and change argument of `eq()`.

Comment: Inside the `.eq()` method you can use -1 as argument to select the last match - `pdf.pq('LTTextBoxHorizontal:contains("Date")').eq(-1).text()`.